# Convert Japanese Half-width ascii to normal ascii in php

Tags: php, ascii

I have a project that will require a person to put in their postal code, and country into a form.  The form then will take that postal code and match it with the country to get the city and state/province/prefecture.   One of my initial target markets is Japan where they use half and full width characters.  My postal codes are all regular ascii codes.  This means any Japanese full or half width number needs to be converted to regular ascii, but I am at a loss as to where to begin to understand how to do this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Docs, articles?  Google has been so far useless to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for mb_convert_kana: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-kana.php